# How to access returned JavaScript promise value in selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to access promise value which I return from JavaScript function. When I try to return it in selenium it returns None. My function works and I can print responseData in console.log. I just struggle with accessing it in python. Is there any way to do it ?

```
   js_value = self.driver.execute_script("""
    var request = "";
        async function final(){
            await send("POST", "https://www.thecrims.com/login",data).then((responseData)=>{
                request = responseData
            });
        };
return request;

""")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(js_value)
```

Comment: should `return request;` go into the js, I mean before end of `"""`?

Comment: @supputuri comiplation mistake, my bad. Already edited.